# IDA 7.0: Why does editing this function result in red-marked stack-pointer offsets?

Tags: ida, disassembly, stack-variables

I tried to fix the size of both the *saved registers* and the *local variable area* using IDA's "Edit function" option as IDA could not recognize it properly by itself.

**Unedited function:**

[image: Unedited function (no red marks)]
[image: Wrong sizes]

**Corrected function:**

[image: Edited function (red marks)]
[image: Correct sizes]

I can't see anything wrong with `[rsp+20h]` as it points into the fixed allocation of 0x48 bytes.
So what does that red mark indicate and what causes it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! What it indicates, to my knowledge, is that it points to something invalid. Since you "corrected" the "local variables area" value, that's arguably the cause. But I'm not sure, doesn't it also point in the middle of a qword there?